# Google Apps Script Not Uploading File: NetworkError: Form Submission Failed

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, google-apps-script

So I am trying to upload a file to my drive using Google Apps Script HTML Service. I have achieved a proof of concept, using only the code needed to upload a file to my drive. It uploads successfully. When I try to integrate this code into the project I am working on, which is a form where a user inputs information, selects a file to upload, and clicks submit, the code fails with 'NetworkError: Form Submission Failed'. I have seen other people ask this on other websites, but no one has provided a solution. Has anyone seen this before? I can provide my code if needed.

UPDATE

I figured out what is causing the error. In my project, once the page loads, the Javascript automatically calls:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(currentUser).getCurrentUser();
```

I tested this, and even when the functions getCurrentUser() and currentUser()do not contain any code (example below), I get the NetworkError: Form Submission Failed message. Anyone seen this before?

```
function currentUser() {

}

function getCurrentUser() {

}
```

Comment: How 'bout sharing some code?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue which came up around June 20th, 2015. Apparently, if you called a google.script.run function before you uploaded the form, the program would fail. It has since been resolved. The code works fine now.